# What is the proper way to manage versions (with svn) of a theme we create?

Tags: theme-development, version-control

I'm developing a theme and want to control its versions.

Here is my development process but I'm not sure if it's proper or not.
Please help give me suggestions.

1. Trunk is the main and the latest stable (release) version.
2. When I'd like to add new features or fix a set of bugs, I create a new branch e.g. branch_v1_01 (=version 1.01)
3. When the 1.01 branch is tested and stable, I merge it back to trunk.
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 and so on.

In the end, we may have something like a trunk, branch1.01, branch1.02, branch1.03 and this means the trunk is the latest stable version (in this case, it's 1.03) and all older versions are still available for clients to download as well (from other older branches).

Is this proper for controlling versions?

Comment: yes, also you can tag noticeable releases though why bother.

Comment: This feels a little subjective to me. Does it work for your and your clients' needs? If so that's what matters.

Comment: @Wyck - Do you mean using 'tag'? I've never used it before. What is it and how can I start learning how to use it?

Comment: @Rarst - I show my process since I know only one way how to work. I'd like to know what the best practice is or how professional people do to control versions. Would you like to share yours?

Comment: Tags are typically something more special than a branch, like say a big 3.0 release, it doesn't really matter if you use them. Your workflow is fine, I suggest just jumping in and starting with it.